# TypeError: Image data can not convert to float. How to mitigate this error?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

```
from numpy import mean,cov,cumsum,dot,linalg,size,flipud
import numpy as np
from pylab import imread,subplot,imshow,title,gray,figure,show,NullLocator

def princomp(A,numpc=0):
    #computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors of covariance matrix
    M = (A-mean(A.T,axis=1)).T # subtract the mean (along columns)
    [latent,coeff] = linalg.eig(cov(M))
    p = size(coeff,axis=1)
    idx = np.argsort(latent) # sorting the eigenvalues
    idx = idx[::-1]       # in ascending order
 #sorting eigenvectors according to the sorted eigenvalues
    coeff = coeff[:,idx]
    latent = latent[idx] # sorting eigenvalues
    if numpc < p and numpc >= 0:
         coeff = coeff[:,range(numpc)] # cutting some PCs if needed
    score = dot(coeff.T,M) # projection of the data in the new space
    return coeff,score,latent

A = imread('beatles.jpg') # load an image
A = mean(A,2) # to get a 2-D array
full_pc = size(A,axis=1) # numbers of all the principal components
i = 1
dist = []
for numpc in range(0,full_pc+10,10): # 0 10 20 ... full_pc
    coeff, score, latent = princomp(A,numpc)
    Ar = dot(coeff,score).T+mean(A,axis=0) # image reconstruction
    # difference in Frobenius norm
    dist.append(linalg.norm(A-Ar,'fro'))
    # showing the pics reconstructed with less than 50 PCs
    if numpc <= 50:
        ax = subplot(2,3,i,frame_on=False)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(NullLocator()) # remove ticks
        ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(NullLocator())
        i += 1 
        imshow(flipud(Ar))
        title('PCs # '+str(numpc))
        gray()

figure()
imshow(flipud(A))
title('numpc FULL')
gray()
show()
```

The error is coming as shown above. This is a sample code on PCA image compression that I found on the net. Suggestions would be helpful. The entire error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 36, in <module>
    imshow(flipud(Ar))
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3157, in imshow
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1898, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5124, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 596, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot plot a complex array with matplotlib `imshow`. So you need to take the real or imaginary part alone, e.g.

```
Ar = dot(coeff,score).T+mean(A,axis=0) # image reconstruction
Ar = Ar.real
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest an alternative to plotting the complex array ??

Comment: Images are not complex, it's just the array that has complex numbers. In any case you would always want to plot either the real or the imaginary part (never both, as that would require 4 dimensions). Is the above solution not working for you? What are you missing?

Comment: Yes, the above solution is working correctly. Thanks. However, if I wanted to plot the imaginary part, what would I have got ?? I want to understand it correctly.

Comment: Here, `Ar = Ar.imag`, but the imaginary part is mostly zero, since you are working with images, which do not have an imaginarey part.